# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o114.save. : java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type OTHER

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Getting below error when inserting records into teradata from sparksql.

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o114.save.
: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type OTHER

Created dataframe with SQL

```
res_evnt = sqlContext.sql("SELECT \
   RESEVNT.reservationSystemCode as RES_SYS_ID \
  ,RESEVNT.recordLocatorID as PNR_REC_LOC_ID \
  ,CAST(substr(RESEVNT.pnrCreateDate,1,10) as DATE) as PNR_CRE_DT \
  ,CAST(replace(RESEVNT.lastUpdateTimestamp,'T',' ') as timestamp) as EVNT_CENT_TZ \
  ,CAST(substr(RESEVNT.lastUpdateTimestamp,1,10)  as DATE)as EVNT_CENT_DT \
  ,'dfdf' as AGNT_OFC_ID  \
  ,CAST(12133.00 as DECIMAL) as AGNT_IATA_NUM\
  ,CAST(0 AS tinyint) as REACOM_EVNT_FLAG \
  ,CAST(0 AS tinyint)as PNR_CANC_FLAG \
  ,'-' as BKNG_CHNL_CDE \
  ,'RD' as RES_TYPE_CDE \
  ,'HFTG' as AGNT_WRKSTN_ID \
  ,'UY' as BKNG_SRCE_CDE \
  ,'JHJ' as AGNT_SINE_ID \
  ,'-' as AGNT_USER_ID \
  ,'JH' as AGNT_CITY_CDE \
  ,'JJ' as AGNT_DTY_CDE \
  ,'-' as AGNT_LOC_CDE \
  ,'YT' as AGNT_CTRY_CDE \
  ,'H' as AGNT_TYPE_CDE \
  ,'1A' as AGNT_DLVY_SYS_ID \
  ,RESEVNT.queueingAgentOfficeID as QUE_AGNT_OFC_ID \
  ,'-' as QUE_AGNT_CITY_CDE \
  ,RESEVNT.receivedFrom as RCVD_FM_TXT \
  ,CAST(4 AS smallint) as PNR_ENVLP_NUM \
  ,'SEL' as DPLOY_EVNT_CDE \
  ,CAST(replace(RESEVNT.lastUpdateTimestamp,'T',' ') as timestamp) as ASOF_CENT_TZ \
   ,1 as ORIGINAL_JOB_ID  \
  ,1 as LATEST_JOB_ID \
  FROM res_evnt RESEVNT")
  insert(res_evnt,"RES_EVNT_POC_NL")

 def insert(dataframe,table):
    dataframe.write.format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", "jxxx")\
    .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", table) \
    .option("user", "dddd")\
    .option("password", "*******") \
    .option("numPartitions", 3) \
    .mode('append') \
    .save()
```

Comment: What version of teradata jdbc are you using?

Comment: And, did you specify teradata driver using `--jar` while launching **pyspark** shell? Like `pyspark --jar 'driver'`